# Confusion with instance method calls of super class from subclass

Tags: ruby

I was just playing to see the instance method calls from the subclass and used the below code of my test:

```
class Animal
  def bark
    p "hukkhh"
  end
end
#=> nil

class Cow < Animal
end
#=> nil

Cow.public_instance_method(:bark)
#=> #<UnboundMethod: Cow(Animal)#bark>

class Cow
  bark
end
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `bark' for Cow:Class
#        from (irb):11:in `<class:Cow>'
#        from (irb):10
#        from C:/Ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

From that code I was confirmed that instance method can't be executed without the object instance of the respective class.

But then I tried below code:

```
def talk
  p "hi"
end
#=> nil

Object.public_instance_method(:talk)
#=> #<UnboundMethod: Object#talk>

class Foo
  talk
end
# prints: hi
#=> "hi"
```

Here the output made me confused with my first test code output.

Could anyone help me to understand the fact behind these above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `talk` you defined is belongs to `Object` which is root of all objects. So `talk` method is available to all object in ruby.

```
def talk
  p "hi"
end

Object.respond_to? :talk  #=> true
```

Now, you defined class `Foo` which is also an ruby object.

```
Foo.is_a? Object  #=> true
Foo.respond_to? :talk  #=> ture
```

So `talk` is available to `Foo` class.

Now you define a class `Animal` with method `bark`

```
class Animal
  def bark
    p "hukkhh"
  end
end
```

`bark` method you define is belong to `Animal` class for now as `instance level` method not class level. It means you need to create instance of class `Animal` to call `bark`.

```
 Animal.respond_to? :bark  #=> false
 Object.respond_to? :bark  #=> false

 Animal.new.respond_to? :bark  #=> true
 Animal.respond_to? :talk   #=> true   #talk is available to Animal also because Animal is also object of Class
 Animal.new.respond_to? :talk  #=> true
```

Now you create class called `Cow` inheriting from `Animal`. So `bark` is available to `Cow` unless it is `overridden`.

```
 class Cow < Animal
 end

 Cow.respond_to? :bark  #=> false
 Cow.new.respond_to? :bark  #=> true
 Cow.respond_to? :talk  #=> true
 Cow.new.respond_to? :talk  #=> true

 Cow.new.bark #=> "hukkhh"
```

So to call `bark` you need to create instance of class.

If you want to call a method of parent which is overridden in child use `super`

```
class Cow < Animal
  def bark
    super
    #do your stuff
  end
end

Cow.new.bark  #=> "hukkhh"
```

Comment: I hope you are a better explainer than me :-)

Comment: why the both `Cow.respond_to? :talk  #=> true` and `Cow.new.respond_to? :talk  #=> true` giving true. I mean `talk` is a class method right? then why `Cow.new.respond_to? :talk  #=> true` ?

Comment: `talk` is method of `Object` which is root of all object and `class` is also a `Object`. You can check this : `class.is_a? Object`. It should return `true`. You can read more about `Object` here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html

Comment: I think `class.is_a? Object` gives a syntax error. You can check like this. `Cow.class` which gives `Class` then check `Class.is_a? Object` which indirectly says `class` is also an `Object`.